# SPA and Knockout.js AddViewModel breakdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, single-page-application

I am having some issues trying to work out what is going ok with MVC SPA and Knockout.
When you create a new project some files are created for knockout.js as examples, but I am struggling to understand what is going on.
Primarily the issue is with the **app.viewmodel.js** and the function **AddViewModel**.

Here is some code which I will attempt to breakdown:

```
self.addViewModel = function (options) {
    var viewItem = {},
        navigator;

    // Example options
    //{
    //    name: "Home",
    //    bindingMemberName: "home",
    //    factory: HomeViewModel
    //}

    // Add view to AppViewModel.Views enum (for example, app.Views.Home).
    self.Views[options.name] = viewItem; // Don't really get this, seems to add a blank object to app.Views.Home

    // Add binding member to AppViewModel (for example, app.home);
    self[options.bindingMemberName] = ko.computed(function () {


        //if (self.view() !== viewItem) {

        //    console.log(self.view()); // returns {}
        //    console.log(viewItem); // returns {}

        //    return null; // should never hit this?
        //}

        return new options.factory(self, dataModel); // This adds our ViewModel to app.home, app.login, etc
    });

    // This checks to see if we have defined a navigatorFactory in our viewmodel (AddViewModel)
    if (typeof (options.navigatorFactory) !== "undefined") {
        navigator = options.navigatorFactory(self, dataModel);
    } else {
        navigator = function () {
            console.log(viewItem);

            self.view(viewItem);
        };
    }

    // Add navigation member to AppViewModel (for example, app.NavigateToHome());
    self["navigateTo" + options.name] = navigator;
};
```

ok, so let's start. First of all we declare 2 variables:

```
    var viewItem = {},
        navigator;
```

**viewItem** is set as a blank object and navigator is undefined.
The first thing we do, is set **self.Views[options.name]** to our **viewItem**, so in my understanding, this would mean:

```
self.Views.Home = {}
```

If we look at the declaration in **app.viewmodel.js** **self.Views** looks like this:

```
self.Views = {
    Loading: {} // Other views are added dynamically by app.addViewModel(...).
};
```

So in here there is already a view called **Loading**. So I am confused as to what is actually happening here.
The next bit of code creates a function:

```
    self[options.bindingMemberName] = ko.computed(function () {           
        return new options.factory(self, dataModel);
    });
```

This is a lot easier to understand. It basically takes our **ViewModel** and adds it to a function under the name of **self.home** (or whatever the **bindingMemberName** of our **ViewModel** is.

This next piece is what confuses me:

```
    if (typeof (options.navigatorFactory) !== "undefined") {
        navigator = options.navigatorFactory(self, dataModel);
    } else {
        navigator = function () {
            console.log(viewItem);

            self.view(viewItem);
        };
    }

    // Add navigation member to AppViewModel (for example, app.NavigateToHome());
    self["navigateTo" + options.name] = navigator;
```

If I strip this down, it basically says if we define a **navigatorFactory**, then the **navigator** (which is currently undefined!) is equal to our **navigatorFactory**. That bit is easy.
It's the next bit I don't get.
It says, else, the **navigator** is a function that returns our **self.view(viewItem)** (remember that **viewItem** is just a blank object.

Then we set **self["navigateTo" + options.name] = navigator**.

So in english, this looks like it is saying, get our blank **viewItem**, assign it to **self.view** for every **ViewModel** we add. Then assign a function returning our **self.view(viewItem)** to our **navigator** variable (which is currently undefined) and assign this to our **self.naviateToHome()** (or whatever).

So to me, that looks like self.navigateToHome(), self.navigateToLogin(), self.navigateToTimbucktoo() would all return the same function with the same **self.view**.

So, can anyone explain to me what is actually happening?

**Update 1**

So, I have figured some things out. First things first, the navigator is setting the current view, so basically **self.Views** looks like this after all the models are added:

```
self.Views = {
    Loading: { }, 
    Home: { }, 
    Login: { }
}
```

So even though **self.view()** returns an empty object, it isn't the same as the **viewItem** because it is stored with the name into **self.Views**.
So, the navigator is actually applying the **viewItem** to **self.views**.
I tested this out by changing the **viewItem** to this:

```
var viewItem = { options.name }
```

and sure enough, **self.Views** looked liked this:

```
self.Views = {
    Loading: { }, 
    Home: { name: "Home" }, 
    Login: { name: "Login" }
}
```

so when we set **self.view** using our **navigator**, the function is called (**app.home** for example) and it runs the code to return our **factory** or null if it isn't the current view.

Comment: Have you considered using Durandal to manage the view engine and routing engine? Durandal combines RequireJS, Knockout, and jQuery to provide a familiar framework for SPA development. http://durandaljs.com/